# Symfony 4 returns null when using json_decode to request

Tags: symfony, symfony4

When I am trying to decode my content it returns null.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $content = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
  dd($content);


}
```

Comment: From [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php#refsect1-function.json-decode-returnvalues), `NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded  `. Does the `content` of request is valid `JSON` ?

Comment: I am not sure if request content is a valid JSON.
This is the data I got when I am trying to dd(dump) the request content:


"name=SAMP4432&ipAddress=192.168.2.1.2711&location=USA%2C+Illnois+City&status=RFO&license=1232132131"

Comment: So if it's not a valid JSON you can't decode it. Check the answer below to verify content is valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also can get all your data from request like this `$request->request->all();` And check that `Content-Type` of your request is `application/json`

Comment: so it should be $content = json_decode($request->request->all(), true); right? then I should set the Content-type to application/json

Comment: no, $request->request->all() will return you array with your body parameters